# How to verify java servlet api call is TLS 1.2 compatible (fastspring payment api)

Tags: java, servlets, tls1.2

Fastspring payment api will be requiring TLS 1.2 in summer, is there some code change needed to this simple tomcat hosted example java servlet code below to make it compatible with TLS 1.2?

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {

                          URL url = new URL("https://api.fastspring.com/company/xxxx/subscription/"+accountKEY);

                          String userpass = "xxxx";
                          String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());

                          connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();                
                          connection.setRequestProperty ("Content-Type", "application/xml");
                          connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);

                          sb.append("<subscription><productPath>/");
                          sb.append(plansw);
                           sb.append("</productPath><no-end-date/></subscription>");

                          connection.setDoOutput(true);
                          connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
                          connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + sb.length());

                          OutputStreamWriter outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                          outputWriter.write(sb.toString());
                          outputWriter.flush();
                          outputWriter.close();


                      OutputStreamWriter wr = null;
                      BufferedReader rd  = null;      
                    String line = null;

                      rd  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                      sa = new StringBuilder();
                      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
                      {
                          sa.append(line + '\n');
                      }
```

Comment: This is usually handled by the JDK. You will have issues if you're on an old (and no longer freely supported) Java version.

Comment: Which JDK supports TLS 1.2?

Comment: The answer for a client appears to be complicated so you should probably do some actual research on that. In any event you would appear to need at least Java 7